# Many to Many Relationship not displaying/save correctly on views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, rails-activerecord

**I have a many to many relationship between work and category.  I want to display the category name of each work on the `work#index` page.**

**Unfortunately it just comes up as empty []:**
[image: example of blank boxes]

**Works#index markup**

```
<% @works.each do |work| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= work.name %></td>
    <td><%= work.subtitle %></td>
    <td><%= work.categories %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', work %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_work_path(work) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', work, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

or i change the markup to `work.categories.name`

[image]

and the form for muliple selecting

```
 <%= fields_for(@work_category) do |cw| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= cw.label "All Categories" %><br />
      <%= collection_select(:categories, :id, @all_categories, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Am I missing a step?  Is it not saving? This is my first rails project; therefore, my first time modeling.  I hope the rest of this documentation helps solves this problem.

---

---

---

**Here's how I add my categories to my works:**
[image: adding categories to works]

---

---

---

I have three models: *work, category, categoryworks*(join table)

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many  :categoryworks
  has_many :works, :through => :categoryworks
end

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :subtitle

  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many  :categoryworks
  has_many :categories, :through => :categoryworks
end

class Categorywork < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :work_id

  belongs_to    :category
  belongs_to    :work
end
```

To my understanding, I add these two lines to the new and edit of my controllers to get them to save to collections.

```
@all_categories = Category.all
@work_category = @work.categoryworks.build
```

Here's the full controller for `works_controller`:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController
  # GET /works
  # GET /works.json
  def index
    @works = Work.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @works }
    end
  end

  # GET /works/1
  # GET /works/1.json
  def show
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @work }
    end
  end

  # GET /works/new
  # GET /works/new.json
  def new
    @work = Work.new

    @all_categories = Category.all
    @work_category = @work.categoryworks.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @work }
    end
  end

  # GET /works/1/edit
  def edit
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])

    @all_categories = Category.all
    @work_category = @work.categoryworks.build
  end

  # POST /works
  # POST /works.json
  def create
    @work = Work.new(params[:work])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @work.save
        format.html { redirect_to @work, notice: 'Work was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @work, status: :created, location: @work }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @work.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /works/1
  # PUT /works/1.json
  def update
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @work.update_attributes(params[:work])
        format.html { redirect_to @work, notice: 'Work was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @work.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /works/1
  # DELETE /works/1.json
  def destroy
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
    @work.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to works_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I've created a many to many relationship in rails  through 2 videos:

[many to many assoication Rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)

[drop down menu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNrNGTe2Zqk&list=PLzofFjB0bZ7VvDSzMH-pAeVGY0SEi7MB5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
I did not update the def create inside of the works_controller

```
params[:works][:id].each do |work|
  if !work.empty?
    @category.categoryworks.build(:work_id => work)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `accepts_nested_attributes_for :categoryworks` in your `Works` model.
See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#configuring-the-model

Also `work.categories` is displaying `Category` because its returning an array. It should be `work.categories.join(', ')` Try that once you fix the problem with your form.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `<td><%= work.category.name %></td>` do it?

**EDIT**

Your `work` model should say `has_many :categories`, not `has_many :category`.

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :subtitle
  validates :name, :presence => true
  has_many :categoryworks
  has_many :categories, :through => :categoryworks
end
```

Comment: ahh yes I forgot to say that it just say "category then" updating the question with image

Comment: updated the post.  when I change it to that it just says category... I dont think it's saving correctly.